# Printing a string with double quotes doesn't show the double quotes

Tags: java, string

I have the below string as shown and as shown below the string should be printed in same format

```
 -t "|" -e "
```

so what I have tried is

```
String s ;
args = String.valueOf(" -t");
args = String.valueOf(args) + String.valueOf(" |");
```

Please advise, is it correct?

Comment: @Murat please advise how it can be implemeted i want to store that string itself

Answer (score 7):

To print `"` you have to print `\"`

```
System.out.println(" -t \"|\" -e \"");
```

Comment: Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html